# lograr que una campo no sea obligatorio en un formulario Django

Tags: html, django, formularios

estoy modificando un proyecto web antiguo de django (1.5), necesito que se puedan recorrer todos los formularios de registro libremente, actualmente no puedo pasar al siguiente formulario sin registrar el campo "email", he intentado modificar el modelo pero aun no logro que el campo me deje de bloquear el botón "siguiente", soy bastante nuevo en el mundillo de django, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

sin introducir nada, el botón "siguiente" esta bloqueado
[image]

al agregar cualquier cosa puedo pasar al siguiente formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en los demas formularios no tengo problemas puedo avanzar y retroceder sin problemas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que si te vas a registrar, por lo menos necesitas tener un campo obligatorio o dos, para que puedas ingresar, de dejarlo opcional sería muy difícil para ti reconocer un usuario o una persona. Si aún así persistes en querer que ese campo no sea obligatorio, te encontraras con cosas que lidiar del lado del cliente y del servidor, y debes proporcionar más información para poder ayudarte a resolverlo. Entre esas cosas, tu código de Javascript que debe hacer que el botón se inhabilite, y del lado del servidor cómo crear registros de acuerdo a los campos que el usuario te envíe

Comment: Hola eh tenido ese problema un par de veces puedes probar mirando el código de la función del formulario hay debe estar la validaciones correspondiente, o si no en el mismo formulario (html) encontraras las respectivas validaciones que te impiden habilitar el botón. espero te sirva.